# how to know what non-running distros are on disks

Tags: linux, distributions

Long time ago I have installed a few Linux distros on various drives / partitions.

Now I need to know what a distro is on a specified drive / partition, without to have to boot it.

I have mounted and I can use, e.g., the directory /boot.

Earlier, a distro KNOPPIX had in this directory (or perhaps in dir with other name) a file showing the knoppix-version. Other distros don't have such a file.

From

/media/sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg

I can read what grub would offer to boot. But this is not what I want.

vmlinux... has information about the kernel

/media/sda3/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic

but this is a binary.

I there a tool to extract more information than the filename says?

But this is not the name, version, release of the distribution.

How can I get that without to boot?

Comment: Many, but not all, will have `/etc/os-release` files, those can be a start. Do you need the distribution name or the kernel info?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways:

1. Run `file /path/to/vmlinuz-something` which will tell you the exact kernel version which you can then google to find out what the distro you're using, e.g.

```
$ file /boot/vmlinuz-5.16.15-201.fc35.x86_64 
/boot/vmlinuz-5.16.15-201.fc35.x86_64: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 5.16.15-201.fc35.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel01.iad2.fedoraproject.org) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 17 05:45:13 UTC 2022, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0XA, Normal VGA
```

2. `strings /bin/any_binary | grep gcc` which show you a GCC release which is normally unique for a specific distro.
3. `cat /etc/os-release` but this doesn't always work and isn't always present.
4. Multiple files in `/var/log` could contain info about your distro.

Comment: thanks, I will try.  Regards anttondhidh